# Why this mysql query works fine when is executed in Workbench but not using JDBC call?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, workbench

Look I have a query similar to:

```
INSERT INTO groups(
    participants, count1, count2, count3) 
SELECT 
0 as participants,
(count1/participants) as count1,
(count2/participants) as count2,
(count3/participants) as count3 WHERE id = 22;
```

Now supose that in the table you have:

groups

```
id    participants         count1       count2       count3
22    5                    10000        10000        10000
```

That query will insert a new row with this values:

```
id    participants         count1       count2       count3
23    0                    2000         2000         2000
```

As I said it works fine in the Workbench but if I run in JDBC (Spring-Java) I get this strangely

```
id    participants         count1       count2       count3
23    0                    2000         NULL         NULL
```

This is the actual query or similar query, this is the original query, I just show the above example to help to understand the problem.

```
INSERT INTO registrations (
  numberOfParticipants,
  eventId,
  eventName,
  STATUS,
  createdOn,
  source,
  sourceDetail,
  paymentType,
  groupId,
  couponId,
  eventModality,
  eventHour,
  groupName,
  couponCode,
  additionalProductQuantities,
  productsPaid,
  discount,
  insurance,
  baseTotal,
  COMMENT,
  processingFee,
  isVolunteer,
  participantType,
  ipNumber,
  refererCodeId
) 
SELECT 
  0 AS numberOfParticipants,
  (SELECT 
    eventId 
  FROM
    groups 
  WHERE id = 27) AS eventId,
  (SELECT 
    lastEventName 
  FROM
    groups 
  WHERE id = 27) AS eventName,
  STATUS,
  createdOn,
  source,
  sourceDetail,
  paymentType,
  27,
  couponId,
  eventModality,
  eventHour,
  (SELECT 
    NAME 
  FROM
    groups 
  WHERE id = 27) AS groupName,
  couponCode,
  additionalProductQuantities,
  (
    productsPaid / numberOfParticipants
  ) AS productsPaid,
  (discount / numberOfParticipants) AS discount,
  (insurance / numberOfParticipants) AS insurance,
  (baseTotal / numberOfParticipants) AS baseTotal,
  NULL,
  (
    processingFee / numberOfParticipants
  ) AS processingFee,
  isVolunteer,
  participantType,
  ipNumber,
  refererCodeId 
FROM
  registrations 
WHERE id = 15787;
```

Comment: My guess is that something is wrong with your JDBC call. Can you share that code?

Comment: Don't call your SQL tables `group`, which is a reserved keyword.  Your raw MySQL code would not even execute, for this and several other reasons.

Comment: Please show us the exact code you are actually running.  Java code would be nice too, but you may start with the raw MySQL code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the syntax from your MySQL query is correct? It should contain a "FROM" statement in the query. Also "group" is reserved keyword in MySQL.

```
INSERT INTO group(
participants, count1, count2, count3) 
SELECT 
0 as participants,
(count1/participants) as count1,
(count2/participants) as count2,
(count3/participants) as count3 
FROM group 
WHERE id = 22;
```

Not enough information is given. This is the best I can give you. Maybe share the java source code will help us provide a better solution.